# (JWNL) Dictionary.getInstance() returns null when putting dictionary in classpath

Tags: null, wordnet

I am using WordNet in a project with JWNL. When I use absolute path

`<param name="dictionary_path" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\WordNet\2.1\dict\"/>`

the Dictionary.getInstance() gives me an instance.

When I use a relative path like `src/main/resources/dict` then it gives me null. I searched through the library code since it is open source and I found that it creates a `new File(path, makeFilename());` where path is the relative path I give him and makeFileName just decides which file to use from the folder and does stuff (it works well with absolute path, so the problem should not be in that method)

A friend of mine said, that maybe the relative path is not seen by the JWNL library from the same point as the project, where I use the library.

We really do not know where to look further. I realize that this might not be enough information to provide an answer, thus I am happy to improve my question according to questions that may arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something else. The XML file from which the relative path was taken is now empty. When I initialize the class, I convert the relative path to absolute path with class path and write it in the xml, from which the external library receives the path and works on it. It is kind of a workaround, but I found no way to push the library to be able to read relative paths.